# How to attach to ghost screen session?

Tags: linux, session, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I've got a screen session running for the user `heechan` on my linux server:

```
heechan@vps3712:~$ ls -laR /var/run/screen/
/var/run/screen/:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  5 root    utmp    100 Aug 31 08:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root    root    640 Sep 18 05:24 ..
drwx------  2 grt     grt      60 Aug 27 04:03 S-grt
drwx------  2 heechan heechan  40 Sep  1 09:44 S-heechan  # <== THIS ONE

/var/run/screen/S-heechan:
total 0
drwx------ 2 heechan heechan  40 Sep  1 09:44 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 root    utmp    100 Aug 31 08:22 ..
```

But when I do `screen -ls` I don't see the session:

```
heechan@vps3712:~$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-heechan.

heechan@vps3712:~$ screen -r
There is no screen to be resumed.
heechan@vps3712:~$
```

Where is this session and how I I resume it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, `/var/run/screen/S-heechan` is empty, so there is no socket file inside.

Your screen is terminated. Perhaps you forgot to detach and exited instead? (To detach, use `ctrl+a d` )